Sum of a subset of i.i.d. Bernoulli r.v.s conditional on their total sum
Suppose we have i.i.d. $\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\sim Bernoulli(p)$ and define $\tau=\sum_{i=1}^n\xi_i,\eta=\sum_{j=1}^{\tau}\xi_j$.
Find $\mathbb{E}\eta$.
Unlike in some of the similar problems solved here, this one involves dependent r.v.s.
I start by computing the expected value of one of the i.i.d. $\xi_i$ conditional on a fixed value of $\tau$ denoted as $k$:
$\begin{align*}
&\mathbb{E}(\xi_i|\tau=k)=1\cdot\mathbb{P}(\xi_i=1|\tau=k)+0=\frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}{k}}=\frac{k}{n}
\end{align*}$
I don't understand how to go from here to $\mathbb{E}(\xi_i|\tau)$. Obviously, if $\tau=k<n$, only $k$ of the variables $\xi_i$ are equal to 1. I've tried to write:
$\mathbb{E}(\xi_i|\tau)\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{i}{n}=\frac{1+n}{2}\cdot n\cdot p$
but I don't think it's right.
Is there something I am doing wrong? How to compute the expected value in question properly?

@Surb how come? I'm quite sure that if $\tau$ is 0, $\xi_i$ is also zero for all $i$.

@Surb how do I compute $\mathbb{E}\eta$ then? $\tau$ obviously makes a difference here. I understand, it's equal to $\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(\eta|\tau)$ but I don't have ideas how to compute $\mathbb{E}(\eta|\tau)$

Detailing your initial calculations:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(\xi_i=1|\tau=k) &= \frac{\mathbb P(\tau=k|\xi_i=1)\mathbb P(\xi_i=1)}{\mathbb P(\tau=k)} \\
&= \frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}p^{k-1}(1-p)^{n-k}p}{\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k}} \\
&= \frac kn
\end{align}
$$
You are almost there. You forgot to reweigh by the probability of $(\tau=k)$. In detail:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb E(\eta) &= \mathbb E(\mathbb E(\eta|\tau)) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \mathbb E(\eta|\tau=k)\mathbb P(\tau=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \left(\sum_{i=1}^k\mathbb E(\xi_i|\tau=k)\right)\mathbb P(\tau=k)\\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n k\mathbb E(\xi_1|\tau)\binom nkp^k(1-p)^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n k\binom {n-1}{k-1}p^k(1-p)^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+1)\binom {n-1}kp^{k+1}(1-p)^{n-1-k} \\
&= p(p(n-1)+1)
\end{align}
$$
where I use the fact that the expected value of $X\sim Binom(n-1,p)$ is $\mathbb E(x) = (n-1)p$. For $n\to\infty$, this simplifies to:
$$
\mathbb E(\eta) \sim p^2n
$$

I' ve tried to do that using the Binomial distribution but failed to simplify the sum. Thank you!

$$\left(\xi_1,\dots,\xi_n\right)'\mid \tau\sim\text{Multivariate Hypergeometic}\left(n, \mathbf{1}_n, \tau\right)$$ with
$\mathbb{E}(\xi_i \mid \tau) = \frac{\tau}{n}$, and $$
\mathbb{E}(\eta)=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{E}\left(\left.\sum_{i=1}^\tau \xi_i \right\vert  \tau\right) \right]=\mathbb{E}\left(\tau \cdot \frac{\tau}{n}\right) = \frac1n \left[\mathbb{V}(\tau)+\mathbb{E}^2(\tau)\right]
$$
where $\tau\sim\text{Binomial}(n,p)$. Plugging in binomial mean and variance gives
$$
\mathbb{E}(\eta)=p(1-p)+np^2.
$$
